# How to play audio from a Google Chrome extension even when closed?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, audio-streaming

I've been making a Google Chrome extension, one that streams an audio file from another site.  I use a Google audio player to do this, and it works fine.

The only problem is, the soundtrack stops playing when I leave the extension is closed. Right now, I don't use Java and would prefer to keep it that way, since I have about zero experience in that field.  If I need to, I am perfectly willing to use it.

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" flashvars="audioUrl=AUDIO URL HERE" src="http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3523697345-audio-player.swf" width="400" height="27" quality="best"></embed>
```

This is what I'm using to play my audio files.  I need to somehow get this to keep playing in the background page.  I've tried making the main background page and the popup page the same; doesn't work.  Here's my manifest file, with the popup and background pages one and the same:

```
"background_page": "Main Code.html",
    "permissions": [
      "background"
],
    "icons" : {
        "16" : "KH icon_16.png",
        "48" : "KH icon_48.png",
        "128": "KH icon_128.png"},
    "browser_action" : {
        "default_icon" : "KH icon_19.png",
        "default_popup": "Main Code.html"
```

Please help me, I've scoured the web for info on this, and being an amateur programmer, I really need help.

Comment: You should avoid having spaces in file names. The direction you should look at is having a `background.html` page and a `popup.html` page. The music will play in the `background.html` page and will be controlled via buttons in `popup.html`.

Comment: Exactly.  HOW do I link the background with the popup page?  That's kind of my question.

Comment: Sending messages between popup page and background page is not a problem. But from you question I understand that you have a problem with playing music from background page, right?

Comment: You can communicate between the popup and the background pages by passing messages: https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html

Answer (score 3):

From what I seem to understand. Your problem is that as soon as you leave the extension the audio stops playing. I would suggest that you instead of using `background_page`, you should add a `background` script.
Use Manifest version 2.
Add a background script like this.

```
"background":
{
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
}
```

play your audio files through this background script.

I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was going crazy trying to find a bug in my code or wav file.

Comment: Does this work if I only have a background *script*, but no background *page*?

I tried to play a sound in the background *script* like so:

 var audio = new Audio("alert.ogg");

 audio.play();

but it doesn't make a sound.  On the developer console, "network" tab, I found that the sound file is loaded successfully each time, but still, no sound is heard.  Can someone help?

Comment: @YanKingYin Hi! Did you find a solution to the above problem you stated? I am trying to figure out a similar issue.

Comment: @Aditya:  In the manifest under "background", I use "page": "background.html", and then in the background.html file I include <script src="background.js"></script>.  Then I am able to play sound in background.js.  Other arrangements may also work, but at least this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Um... I think you mean Javascript and not Java (2 completely different languages - not related in any way what so ever).  Next you should get rid of all the spaces in your file names, not only is this terrible practice but your manifest is probably having trouble identify all of the the extensions components.

Finally... It may work to play the audio from the background page.  Refer to the Google Chrome Extensions API for what a background page is.  The code on the popup is not going to be the same as the code in the background page.  To talk between the two refer to the chrome.extension.* package API.  For a quick solution [here is a socket utility](https://github.com/jjNford/chrome-extension-socket) that provides two way communication.